# Selecting features by expression with SQL syntax in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sql, select-by-attribute, maximum

I have a table (shapefile) in QGIS where I want to select features that satisfies this condition:

group by a field (`"join_label"`) and within the `"grouped field"`, pick the attribute with the highest area (the area has already been calculated in a separate field)

I tried to do this:

```
maximum("Area", group_by:="join_label")
```

This expression selects everything in the table.

I wanted to use the "Execute SQL" function but how do I write the query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectormiscellaneous.html#execute-sql) function:

```sql
SELECT
 join_label,
 MAX("Area") as max_area,
 geometry
FROM
  input1
GROUP BY
  join_label
```

Not forgetting to select the layer in the `Additional input datasources` at the top of the tool window (which gets the name `input1` in your expression).

Answer (score 7):

Use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#selecting-features) with this expression:

```
area = maximum(area, group_by:=join_label)
```

Comment: it works as well ! Thank you !!